# Can't Boot into either Windows or Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

## History

I first installed Windows 8.1 and left around 60GBs Unallocated. Then I tried installing Ubuntu with a USB, but the partition table I had made did not show up. I then tweaked some settings in my BIOS/UEFI and then again tried still with no luck. Finally I did `sudo gdisk /dev/sda` and got rid of my GPT Partition but left the MBR(or i don't know windows partition) untouched. Then I tried and it successfully showed the partition table and I was able to make changes.

I made:

1. [sda5] linux-swap of 1.91 GiB
2. [sda6] '/' or root of 19.07 GiB
3. [sda7] '/home' of 34.44 GiB

with 1.02 MiB Unallocated

also, my sda1-3 are for windows (1-System Reserved, 2-OS, 3-Storage Drive) and sda5,6,7 are sub parts of sda4

I completed the installation and then I was successfully able to run ubuntu, but the problem was that there was no option to boot into windows, so I searched and found out there were some problems with grub. I made some tweaks and restarted and even ubuntu stopped working. So I again searched and with the help of live USB made some changes.

Changes made were reinstalling grub 2 in sda6.

## Problem

But the problem came `error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found` and then I did that (reinstall) which led me to `gnu grub minimal bash like line editing.....` Now what I have is all my Operating Systems perfectly lying in my hard disk but I cannot boot any of them. All I can do is boot from live USB. I also tried to install grub 2 again but with no luck. It says `Installing for i386-pc platform` and then `Installation finished. No errors reported.` But still does not work. I have even tried resetting my BIOS settings.

PS: Laptop - Lenovo B490

Comment: Did you try booting with a USB drive and using [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) ?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate Yeah, I have tried that. But it was unsuccessful and maybe even that broke my system

Answer (score 5):

You cannot get rid of a GPT partition. GPT is a table type as is an MBR partition table. Since it appears you have a Windows 8 installation disc you can always disable UEFI, and install both operating systems in CSM (legacy bios mode) with an MBR partition table.

If you wish to install under UEFI then use GPT for both operating systems. If Ubuntu isn't recognizing your partitions, open Gparted in the Ubuntu live-cd and verify that it DOES see the table. I would suggest creating the partition table in Gparted, installing Windows, and then installing Ubuntu.